# How to cast Dictionary<T, List<T>> to IReadOnlyDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: c#, .net

The `Dictionary<T, List<T>>` is a private member and external methods should not modify its content. Therefore I want to create a public property making it readonly. But I don't know how to do it. It seems only possible when the value type of dictionary is not a mutable type.

Comment: Can you also please share some code where you've tried to accomplish your problem? Where is your problem when casting?

Comment: If you want to make sure that your original Dictionary is not modified, you usually either create a read-only copy on the fly when it is accessed, or you maintain a read-only copy and expose that. Otherwise, whoever accesses the reference can always cast it back to a mutable type. If you want your Dictionary to handle these operations itself, i'm afraid you have to code your own wrapper.